# Proof that improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}(1+\sin(x^2)) dx$ exists

Tags: improper-integrals

> I want to prove that the following integral exists:
>   $$
> \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(1+\sin\left(x^2\right) \right) dx
> $$

First I tried to calculate it by splitting it up (multiplied it out and then separated it at the sum symbol) but then I got stuck.

Then I tried an other way. An improper Integral $[0,\infty)$ exists, if $0\leq \int{f(x)}\leq \int{g(x)}$, if $\int{g(x)}$ exists (obviously $f:=e^{-x}...$).

Since $|\sin(x^2)|\leq1$ therefore 
$$
0 \le \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(1+\sin\left(x^2\right) \right) dx
  \le 2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx = 2,
$$
so the improper integral exists and is less or equal then 2 (in fact it is approx. 1,27 I think).

Is this right or would you use another approach?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Exactly $\frac 75$ and your approach is good to me